# Saving date with events in mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to insert dates with events in the database, first I populate table with dates and textarea,
as seen in the image,. After filling the textarea, you will hit submit to save the events in the database, only the textarea with value is suppose to be stored but what is happening, all the dates is saving even without events input. [image]

Below is the codes for saving in the database.

```
 if(isset($_POST['submit_calendar']))
        {
                $memo = $_POST['memo'];
                $cMonth = $_POST['cal_month'];
                $cYear = $_POST['cal_year'];

                $timestamp = mktime(0,0,0,$cMonth,1,$cYear);
                $maxday = date("t",$timestamp);
                $thismonth = getdate ($timestamp);
                $startday = $thismonth['wday'];

                for ($i=0; $i<$maxday+$startday; $i++) 
                {
                    if($i < $startday) continue;

                    if($memo == NULL)
                    {
                        $i++;
                        continue;
                    }
                    else    
                    {
                        $date = $cYear."/".$cMonth."/".($i-$startday+1);
                        $event = $memo[$i-$startday];

                        $query = "INSERT INTO calendar SET cal_date='$date', cal_event='$event'";
                        $q = mysql_query($query);
                    }
                }   
        }
```

Comment: Check if event is filled or not. If filled then insert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
if(strlen(trim($event))>0){
  $query = "INSERT INTO calendar SET cal_date='$date', cal_event='$event'";
}
```

Comment: it works, but whats the diff with if($event == NULL),

Comment: NULL is taken into account if a variable has not been set any value. SO in your case if there is space then $event==NULL will fail

Comment: dont you think !empty(trim($memo)) would be more elegant? And btw. Im not sure what you want to accomplish, but your code wont work if you want to save more than one memo with one submit